# Given value in output in db2

Tags: db2

I have a query where I am getting child emails for a parent email after few joins

```
select * from user_email  WHERE user_eaddr_txt in (select u.ADDR_TEXT from cust_mail c, intnl_user u where c.cust_id=u.cust_id and c.cust_eaddr_txt in ('TEST@GMAIL.COM')) ;
```

I get all child emails linked to that parent email.

```
testchild@gmail.com
```

Is there anyway I can get Parent email along with child email in the result set?

testchild@gmail.com TEST@GMAIL.COM

Comment: Uh, what's wrong with a regular `JOIN` on the outermost level.  That should do it, right?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this

```
SELECT c.cust_eaddr_txt as parent_email
     , u.ADDR_TEXT as child_email
  FROM cust_mail c  
 INNER JOIN intnl_user u  ON c.cust_id=u.cust_id   
 WHERE c.cust_eaddr_txt = 'TEST@GMAIL.COM'
```

if you need additional details from the user_email table you need to join that as well

```
SELECT c.cust_eaddr_txt as parent_email
     , u.ADDR_TEXT as child_email
     , ue.*
  FROM cust_mail c  
 INNER JOIN intnl_user u  ON c.cust_id=u.cust_id  
 INNER JOIN user_email ue ON ue.user_eaddr_txt = u.ADDR_TEXT
 WHERE c.cust_eaddr_txt = 'TEST@GMAIL.COM'
```

I assumed an inner join but depending on your model and needs it could be a left join as well.